# Как создать видео файл с черным экраном и звуком с определенными параметрами с помощью ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Есть видео файл **mp4** с параметрами:

**Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 960x576 25fps [V: h264 baseline L3.1, yuv420p, 960x576]
Audio: muLaw 8000Hz mono 64kbps [A: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s]**

Требуется создать аналогичный по параметрам видео файл с черным экраном (blank video) с помощью ffmpeg

Пытаюсь так:

**ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=960x576:rate=25:color=black -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=8000:cl=mono -c:a pcm_mulaw -t 1000 -b:v 64k output.mp4**

Но ругается, что audio кодек не поддерживается в этом контейнере...

Если меняю расширение на avi, файл создается, но в дальнейшем при конкатенации с вышеуказанным файлом, выдает ошибку... вероятно из-за несовпадения форматов аудио

Comment: там я был, как прописать параметры аудио кодека, так как видео формат  вроде совпадает...

Comment: ffprobe на  том видео что покажет? может это не mp4

Comment: Это показывает Input #0, mpeg, from '20230829_0605_0734.mp4':
  Duration: 01:29:14.08, start: 29.906689, bitrate: 216 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 960x576, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у Вас не mp4 файл, а mkv,flv или avi с расширением mp4.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats#Audio_coding_formats_support